# Rails Import/Parse from CSV UTF-8 Missing Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm working on allowing users to import data from a CSV file. Right now all the fields will import correctly, except whatever is the first field.

What I've discovered is the file type is affecting the import.

My code looks like:

```
class Import < Operation
require 'csv'
def call(file, training_event_id)
  csv_data = CSV.parse(file.read, headers: true)
  list_occo = []
  csv_data.each do |row|
    occupant = Occupant.new
    occupant.account_number = row['Account Number']
    occupant.check_in = row['Check In']
    binding.pry
    occupant.training_event_id = training_event_id
    list_occo << occupant
  end
  binding.pry
  occo_errors = check_file(list_occo)
  list_occo.each(&:save) if occo_errors.empty?
  return occo_errors
end
```

When I do the binding.pry and check on occupant I'm getting nil on the Account Number when doing CSV UTF-8. If I switch to straight up CSV not an issue. Is there a way to convert/switch a CSV UTF-8 to CSV? I thought/tried using some sort of encoding on the parse like: encoding: 'iso-8859-1' but that didn't work.

Is there a way to convert the CSV UTF-8 or is there a way to do a straight up file format check to ensure it's CSV and not CSV UTF-8?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone comes across this issue in the future. I looked at the file in the rails console using CSV.read(file.path) and noticed U+FEFF preceding the first column header. There's a rabbit hole of information about BOM and UTF-8 issues. Without wanting to do a CSV/File.open I attempted things like doing a split, gsub, file checks on utf-8, etc. Then I simply changed the csv_data line to be:

```
csv_data = CSV.parse(File.read(file, encoding: 'bom|utf-8'), headers: true)
```

Then in my controller I updated it from (params[:file]) to (params[:file].path) as I was getting an error of

> no implicit conversion of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into
>   String

Hopefully this helps someone else.